# ¿Cuál es la etimología del topónimo "Chile"?

Tags: etimología, historia, chile

Quiero saber por qué ese angosto país ubicado en Sudamérica que limita con Argentina, Bolivia y Perú tiene ese nombre tan llamativo. Lo que pasa es que en México, (y creo que también Centroamérica) se le llama "chile" al pimiento picante, que en otros países se le llama ají. Así que me gustaría saber la etimología del nombre de dicho país de Sudamérica y si acaso tendrá relación al uso que se le da a la palabra en algunos países para referirse ese pimiento.

Comment: Me interesa también la etimología de la isla de Chiloé.  ¿será relacionada?

Answer (score 1):

Encontré esto, si es a lo que te referías

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origen_del_top%C3%B3nimo_Chile

Comment: en lugar de poner un enlace, por favor copia (y referencia) las partes más relevantes del enlace que proporcionas. Dale a [edit] para hacerlo, ¡gracias!